# Accessing LinEst output in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use the coefficient from LinEst but LinEst returns an array. What is the best way to access the parts of the array output? What data types will the parts of the array be?

Comment: Can you provide some sample VBA code using the `LINEST` function, showing inputs and outputs? I keep getting **Unable to get the LinEst property of the WorksheetFunction class**. You should probably be able to store the results in a Variant variable, and after stepping through with the debugger, examining the variable.

Comment: In general, array access in VBA is done using `()` -- `Dim arr : arr = Array(1,2,3) : Debug.Print arr(1) 'prints 2`. Keep in mind that you don't need a variable of a specific array type in order to hold an array, or to access the values.

Answer (score 0):

This solution may help someone, although I appreciate it is an old question.

I found that the `WorksheetFunction.Linest` function returns the error message `Unable to get the LinEst property of the WorksheetFunction class`, for all manner of errors. So by trial and error(lots) I finally got to this solution:

```
Sub CalcTrend()
'--------------
' To Determine a simple linear trend of the form y = mx + b

'First declare arrays for x and y data series
Dim x() As Double, y() As Double
' Next declare a variant array for the Linest return values
Dim RtnArray() As Variant
' Also declare simple variable for the individual parameters
Dim m As Double, b As Double, r2 As Double
' Finally declare and index variable for For-Next loop
Dim i As Long

' Both x() and y() arrays MUST be same size
' and assuming the data is in a worksheet in columns x any y then,
'  to populate the arrays, for example
' With Worksheet
'    RowsInDataSet = .Range(.Cells(firstrow, xCol), .Cells(lastRow, xCol)).Rows.Count
' End With
ReDim x(0 To RowsInDataSet)
ReDim y(0 To RowsInDataSet)

For i = 0 To UBound(x)
    x(i) = X_Range.Cells(i + 1, 1) 'Replace X_Range with worksheet range for x series
    y(i) = Y_Range.Cells(i + 1, 1) 'Replace y_Range with worksheet range for y series
Next i

' Now run the Linest function ...
DataArray = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(y, x, , True)
' ... and the results can be found as follows
' Slope
m = DataArray(1, 1)
' Y-intercept
b = DataArray(1, 2)
' Coefficient of determination (how well the data correlates to the line)
r2 = DataArray(3, 1)

End Sub
```

See the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.linest?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm137103)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue#return-value) for a full map of all the Return Array values.

This solution is shown as a Sub to demonstrate obtaining the WorksheetFunction return values. For practical purpose using a Function with ByRef arguments for return array could be more useful.